# Can one protect Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID of their device?

Tags: android

Is there a way in android that one can disallow apps from fetching android id without seeking some permission?

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String androidId = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Also, can I programmatically know all other apps that are fetching/using it.

Comment: I think both are impossible.

Comment: If you want to be anonymous to the certain app you could create new user for the device you want to use the app on. That's the only way I can think of